# Trigonometric equation Mathematica

Tags: parameters, wolfram-mathematica, equation

I try to solve this trigonometric equation with Mathematica. I have two parameters (ktr and kr) without values. I would like to have the solution with these parameters in order to find later numerical values. This is the equation:

```
ktr^2 + ktr*(1/(
   1 + Cosh[λ]*Cos[λ]))(λ*ktr/kr*(Sinh[λ]*Cos[λ] - Cosh[λ]*Sin[λ]) - 
     λ^3*(Sin[λ]*Cosh[λ] + Cos[λ]*Sinh[λ])) + 
  λ^4*ktr/kr*(1 - Cosh[λ]*Cos[λ])/(1 + Cosh[λ]*Cos[λ]) == 0
```

I try with Solve, NSolve, TrigExpand but due to the parameters ktr and kr I cannot plot or find a solution. Has someone any ideas? The unknown parameter is λ and should be expressed as a function of kr and ktr.

Comment: The parameter is λ fow which I search a solution. ktr and kr are solution independed variables.

Comment: you should edit the question if you need to clarify. There is no chance you are going to symbolicaly solve for lambda if thats the question.

Answer (score 1):

One useful solution found for `ktr`.

```
sol = Solve[ktr^2 + ktr*(1/(
   1 + Cosh[λ]*Cos[λ]))(λ*ktr/kr*(Sinh[λ]*Cos[λ] - Cosh[λ]*Sin[λ]) - 
     λ^3*(Sin[λ]*Cosh[λ] + Cos[λ]*Sinh[λ])) + 
  λ^4*ktr/kr*(1 - Cosh[λ]*Cos[λ])/(1 + Cosh[λ]*Cos[λ]) == 0, {ktr, kr}]
```

> Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
>
> ```
> {{ktr -> 0}, {ktr -> (λ^3 (-λ + λ Cos[λ] Cosh[λ] + kr Cosh[λ] Sin[λ] + 
>       kr Cos[λ] Sinh[λ]))/(
>    kr + kr Cos[λ] Cosh[λ] - λ Cosh[λ] Sin[λ] + λ Cos[λ] Sinh[λ])}}
> ```

Plotting `ktr` vs `λ` for a range of integer values of `kr`.

```
Show[Table[Plot[Last[ktr /. sol], {λ, 0, 2 Pi}], {kr, 0, 20}], 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["λ", 14], Style["ktr", 14]}, Ticks -> {{0, Pi, 2 Pi}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I did not set the question correctly. The parameter is λ. For this parameter I am trying to find the solution.

Comment: You plot for λ and I can see where λ takes yero values and this is a solution. But I need λ as a function of ktr and kr. Then bz giving ktr and kr values I found specific values for λ.

Comment: @GeMa Solve can't find a solution.

Comment: The other way as you suggested is to first give values for kr and ktr and then solve for λ.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what are you trying to solve it for?

Comment: @ E.Doroskevic it is the frequency function of a beam free at its one end and elastically supported at the other. I would like to find the values of λ as  a function of the spring constants kr (rotational) and ktr (translational). It would be helpfull if I had the solution for λ as a function of kr and ktr